# Moving image while scroll down and up on path

Tags: javascript, html, css

I design this a ball (images) on the website when scrolling down or up, the ball gonna stick on that path while scrolling.

Screenshot:

[image]

But I don't know how to stick that ball on the path.

I tried like

```
if (s > 40 && s <= 60) {
            if(scrollPosition == 0){
                position += 2;
            }
            if(scrollPosition == 1){
                position -= 2;
            }
        } else if (s > 60 && s <= 80) {
            if(scrollPosition == 0){
                position -= 2;
            }
            if(scrollPosition == 1){
                position += 2;
            }
```

but too weird.. here is my code 
https://codepen.io/ookangzheng/pen/eEyqjJ?editors=0011

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried a few way to solve your problem. First of all, I think it is hard to use the s element in your coding to guide the frequency of increase the position because it seen different every you scrolling.

My suggestion is [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vJdEXJ?editors=0011). Try to use the whole height and the window height to calculate the percentage and use it. Also, I am not going to use that much point for changing the position because scrolling duration is very large. It is not necessary to point too small.

FYI, I have added a `transition-duration: 1s;` and `transition-property: all;` in your css it made the smooth movement.

**Percentage coding**

```
    var s = $(this).scrollTop();
        d = $(document).height(),
        c = $(this).height();
    var length = d - c;
    var pctScrolled = Math.floor(s / length * 100) ;
```

**Calculate position**

```
    if( s < 33){
        position = 60;
    }
    if(s > 33 && s < 66){
        position = 40;
    }
    if(s > 66 && s < 100){
        position = 60;
    }
    if(s == 100 || s == 0 ){ //initial the position on top and bottom
         position = 50;
    }
```

Hope you find your way!